# How do I access FSharp.Data.JsonExtensions?

Tags: f#, f#-data

Sorry if this question is a bit unclear. It was the best I could do in my state of confusion about packages in F# 4.0.

The book `Expert F# 4.0` by Don Syme, Adam Granicz, and Antonio Cisternino contains code that processes JSON data. The code starts with

```
open FSharp.Data
open FSharp.Data.JsonExtensions
```

I have `FSharp.Data` installed in Visual Studio. Still, the word "JsonExtensions" gets red squiggles under it and the rest of the code does not compile.

Going to `Add References` in the Solution Explorer I did not find a package `FSharp.Data.JsonExtensions`. I also looked under `NuGet` and found no package `FSharp.Data.JsonExtensions`. There is documentation for [`JsonExtensions`](http://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Data/reference/fsharp-data-jsonextensionsmodule.html)
which suggests it is a module. However, using the dot in Visual Studio it does not appear under `FSharp.Data.` (There is only one entry: `Unit Systems`)

How can I make the code in this module available so I can run the code in the book?

Comment: Which version of VS are you using?

Comment: Are you sure that package was installed correctly?

Comment: @FoggyFinder - I am using VS Community Edition Version 14.0.25431.01 Update 3 with Microsoft .NET Framework Version 4.6.01586.

Comment: @FoggyFinder - No, I am not sure the package was installed correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because actually you don't have FSharp.Data installed (So Foggy is right above). There is an FSharp.Data namespace but you need to nuget the package to be able to use it. So go to `Tools | Nuget Package Manager | Manage Nuget Packages for Solution` and download the latest and greatest `FSharp.Data`. This will automatically add it to your references file in VS:

[image: Nuget the package]

See:

[image]

Now you can use it:

[image]

If you are using it from an .fsx script make sure to reference it with `#r`

`#r @"..\packages\FSharp.Data.2.3.2\lib\net40\FSharp.Data.dll"`

In that case you can just right-click on the References (after nugetting) and VS will generate you the path:

[image]

If you don't see `Send to F# Interactive` I strongly suggest you install the [Visual F# Power Tools](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=FSharpSoftwareFoundation.VisualFPowerTools).

You can explore other ways of accessing/serializing JSON files: there is the [JSON type provider](http://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Data/library/JsonProvider.html), [Newtonsoft JSON](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Introduction.htm), [FSharplu](https://github.com/Microsoft/fsharplu), [Chiron](https://github.com/xyncro/chiron), and [FSPickler](http://mbraceproject.github.io/FsPickler/).

Comment: I went to Manage Packages for Solution and in the tab Installed clicked on FSharp.Data, which has a green checkmark. A window opened on the right showing two checkboxes (the first one for all projects, the second one for the current project). If I check them I can press the Uninstall button to uninstall FSharp.Data (I did not do that). The Install button does nothing. So it looks like I do have FSharp.Data v.2.3.2 installed for this project. What am I missing?

Comment: Can u edit your question and add a screenshot of your References, and maybe the contents of your fsproj file. Or just create a new solution with a new project and follow the steps in the answer.

Comment: I figured out the problem. Sorry, it was a silly mistake. I was working with a .fsx file, so I had to  Send to F# Interactive as you suggested. What confused me was that I was not entering code on the F# Interactive window, but on the .fsx file through the editor. I knew I had to Send to F# Interactive to run the code in the F# Interactive window but I did not know that Intellisense would not capture FSharp.Data on the editor while I was editing the .fsx file.

Comment: Great. In that case use the #r directive on top of the file.

Comment: Thanks. I also just found out I can do:
#if INTERACTIVE
#r @"C:\Users\ ..."
endif
which will run the #r directives only if in interactive sessions.